# question on mixing pdf and probability

Tags: probability

I am trying to follow the laplace's rule of succession.
I can follow the main idea of it.
But can't follow some details.

The version I'm studying has some steps which seem intuitively correct, but not rigorous dealt with.
I just want to know if I need more advanced math to understand more rigorously or is it just me that who can't connect the dots..

$S_n$: # of sun rises in n days.
$p$: probability of sun rise, P = Unif(0,1) prior.
$f$: pdf of $p$

So the rule of succession problem tries to find probability of sun rising tommorow given that sun has risen previous k days.
When the probability of sun rising is some unknown p, and we believe it's drawn from uniform distribution prior before we have any evidence.

First, when applying the bayesian formula.
I was wondering how one could deal with single value of continuous random variable because it's defined to be 0

$$ P(p | S_n=k) = \frac{P(S_n=k|p)*P(p)}{P(S_n=k)} $$

We dodge the problem of  probability of continuous random variable taking exact value such as $P(p)$ by replacing it by $f(p)$.

$$ f(p | S_n=k) = \frac{P(S_n=k|p)*f(p)}{P(S_n=k)} $$

Well I can see that is reasonably correct, but bayes theorem wasn't stated in terms of pdf.

Also, I find it mysterious that one can talk about $P(S_n=k|p)$ when $P(p=p_0)$ is supposedly 0, and I wonder how one imagine the $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ when B is a continuous variable

Would I be able to rigorously extend bayes theorem from Pr version to pdf version with first or 2nd year college math? (not rigorously in absolute sense, but with similar rigour practiced in those college years).
Maybe better question would be is there anything subtle (but glossed over) than the ones non rigorous calculus would gloss over? or is it in the similar stuff that got glossed over? or nothing is glossed over, it's just me feeling something is being glossed over.

Another related question is that..

I can see the definition of $E(X) = \int x*pdf(x) dx$
is intuitively capture the definition of $E(X)$ in discreet case.
(I can visualize taking the sum of small rectangles)

But, it's hard to feel 100% confident at
Probability of sun rising: $\int_0^1 p*f(p) dp$

The probability can also be interpreted using indicator variable Y's $E(Y)$ where $p*f(p)$ is considered as the probability density of random variable Y.

I maybe able to follow $\int_0^1 p*f(p) dp = E(Y)$
from left to right,
but it's hard to imagine a variable $Y$ with the $p*f(p)$ probability and compute $E(Y)$.
How one could come up with the probability $p*f(p)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this 100% rigorously, then you need to use measure theory which is going to get fairly complicated fairly fast.

You can do this fairly rigorously with pdf’s if you’re comfortable with taking limits and understand derivatives.

For the most part, a pdf can be treated equivalent to a probability. If $f$ is the pdf for p, we have that the $f(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+} P(p\in[x,x+\epsilon])/\epsilon$. This means that for any formula with P(p) (or its conditionals) on both sides, you can restrict to $[x,x+\epsilon]$, divide by $\epsilon$ on both sides and take the limit as it goes to 0. In this way the standard probability Baye’s Law implies the pdf variant.

Similarly, you are correct that a literal approach to $P(A|B)=P(A,B)/P(B)=0/0=?$ gives nonsense. Generally, we’re implicitly doing some kind of limiting operation, $P(A|B=b)= \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+} P(A|B\in[b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon])$
$=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{P(A,B\in[b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon])}{P (B\in[b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon])} $
In this way, we can define a continuous pdf variant of our normal conditional formula.

See this discussion for the importance of exactly what kind of limiting operation you’re doing mattering: [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel–Kolmogorov_paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox)

Expectancy can be defined in the same way, where we define any generic function as a sum of indicator functions or as the limit of a bunch of discrete variables over lots of small intervals and then calculate accordingly.